# why i am not getting a list of item present in my cart into the url

Tags: spring, jsp

I want to send a list of items for order but none of  item "id" is present in url.

[image: List of Items present in cart]

[image: output]

**Cart.jsp**

```
        <c:forEach items="${listCart}" var="items">
            <tr>
                <td style="text-align: center">${items.id}</td>
                <td style="text-align: center">${items.name}</td>
                <td style="text-align: center"><fmt:formatNumber type="currency">${items.price} 
     </fmt:formatNumber></td>
                <td>
                   <input type="number" style="width:20 px; height:4px" id="quantity_${items.id}" 
      value="${items.quantity}" />
                <td style="text-align: center"><fmt:formatNumber 
    type="currency">${items.price.longValue() * items.quantity}</fmt:formatNumber></td>
                <td style="text-align: center"><a href="<c:url value="/view/cart/removeItem"/>? 
      id=${items.id}" >Remove</a></td>
        </c:forEach>
    </table>

            <div class="col-md-5">
            <a class="btn btn-light btn-xl" href="<c:url value="/order"/>${items.id}">Order Now!</a>
        </div>
```

This is controller class where the items will stored to database and will place for order.
**Controller Class**

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping("/order/{id}")
public String createOrder(@PathVariable(value = "id") int id) {
    customerOrderModel customerOrder = new customerOrderModel();
    Cart cart = cartdao.getCartByID(id);
    customerOrder.setCart(cart);

    CustomerModel customer = cart.getCustomer();
    customerOrder.setCustomerID(customer);
    customerOrder.setBillingAddress(customer.getBillingAddress());
    customerOrder.setShippingAddress(customer.getShippingAddress());

    orderDao.addCustomerOrder(customerOrder);

    return "redirect:/view/cart/addItem";

   }
```

Comment: The variable `items` is valid within the `forEach` loop only. And it probably refers to a single cart item. Did you mean to sue some other variable, some sort of cart id?

Answer (score 0):

I think, you have pasted this code in wrong place, it should be with in foreach loop, because the "items" scope with in foreach. just put this code with for lop

```
  <div class="col-md-5">
            <a class="btn btn-light btn-xl" href="<c:url value="/order"/>${items.id}">Order Now!</a>
        </div>
```